# How can I avoid my web browser from redirecting to localhost using WAMP in Windows7?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-7, redirect, localhost

I'm currently using Windows 7 with WAMP to try and work on some software, but my web browsers will not accept cookies from the "localhost" domain. I tried creating a few bogus domains in my hosts file by pointing them to 127.0.0.1 but when I type them in I am automatically redirected back to localhost. I have also configured virtualhosts in apache to correspond with the domains I added to the hosts file and it still redirects back to localhost. Is there anything special I must do on Windows 7 to get around this localhost redirect?

Thanks for looking :)

I'll include my host file here:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
# 127.0.0.1       localhost
# ::1             localhost
127.0.0.1        magento.localhost.com www.localhost.com
```

Thanks for looking :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a similar example from C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf on my own PC.

Please note that this requires a static IP address on your computer; do not use DHCP on the PC which you are using for development. And as Alberto says, you will need corresponding entries in your hosts file (in c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost.config.local
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
 <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    ServerAlias 192.168.1.12
    DocumentRoot "D:/www"
 <Directory "D:/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mypc
    ServerAlias mypc.config.local
    DocumentRoot "D:/Web-Sites/www"
 <Directory "D:/Web-Sites/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have several domains setup in that way and works fine, they key is match the `ServerName` with the alias used in **hosts** (note that you don't have to use .com or .net in the name):

In **httpd.conf**:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test
    DocumentRoot "D:/web/test"
    ErrorLog C:\Temp\Logs\Apache\test-error.log  ; optional, but useful for development
    CustomLog C:\Temp\Logs\Apache\test-access.log common  ; optional, but useful for development
</VirtualHost>
```

In **hosts**

```
127.0.0.1    test
```

This should enable requests to `http://test/` without redirection.

Answer (score 0):

Why not browse to the website using your local IP (httx://192.168.x.x) instead of httx://127.0.0.1 or httx://localhost?

sorry about the htt**x**...

Comment: They both redirect back to http://localhost too. :-(

Answer (score -1):

If you use 127.0.0.1 in your /etc/hosts for your *fake* domains, they will always go to localhost.

You should use the IP address of your network card, or add a secondary IP address to your network card and use it for your tests.

Comment: In name resolution there is not fake or valid. And it is working with loopback address.